# Setting with Copy Warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
Y.drop(Y.head(1).index, inplace=True)
```

The above statement gives the following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `inplace=True` is forcing a change in `Y`.  `Y` is a view of another dataframe.  Somewhere prior to this line of code when you created `Y`, you made it in such a way as to make it a view.  There are many ways in which this could've happened.  The quickest way for me to help you solve your problem is to not use `inplace` and just reassign.

```
Y = Y.drop(Y.head(1).index)
```

Or Better yet

```
Y = Y.iloc[1:]
```